# Something black in Glass render in Cycles

Tags: cycles-render-engine, glass

I'm trying to figure out the solution for this problem.

This is a screenshot of the render of toruses with default glass shader in absolutely whire environment.

[image]

As you can see there are some black artifacts (looks like reflections) on the glass.

Also notice that the number of the transmission bounces, global bounces, and translucent bounces are pretty high. There is also no clamping.

What is the problem? And how to solve it? Any ideas?

Blender 3.1
For this experiment I used CPU render.

Comment: I would suggest you increase the _Max Bounces_ for _Glossy_.

Comment: @moonboots The screenshot shows the _Light Paths_ settings... this is _Cycles_.

Comment: oops ok sorry....

Comment: Hi :). There are many possible reasons. Search this site, it could be anything from glossy bounces, to HDRI ;)

Comment: You can also share part of the file https://pasteall.org/blend/ ;)

Answer (score 1):

It was glossy bounces. Thanks!